# Solving angles in a parallelogram, geometry

Tags: geometry

Could Sonoma please help me answer question 12 on this worksheet? I am not sure what equation I should write.

[image]

Comment: What do you know about $\angle P$ vs $\angle R$?  And the sum of all of the angles in a parallelogram?

Comment: What does the theorem of parallel lines say, @alex01001?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that a parallelogram has parallel sides. That is, $PQ || RS$. Thus line $PS$ forms a transversal between $PQ$ and $RS$. We see that angles $Q$ and $P$ are **consecutive interior angles**, and by the consecutive interior angle theorem, we find that $\angle Q$ is supplementary to $\angle P$ Thus, $m\angle Q + m\angle P = 180$, and by substitution,

$$(3x + 5) + (8x-12) = 180^\circ$$
$$11x - 7 = 180^\circ$$
$$11x = 187$$
$$x = 17$$

and thus
$$m\angle P = 3(17) + 5 = 56, \qquad m\angle Q = 8(17)-12 = 124$$

Additionally, $QR$ forms a transversal between $PQ$ and $RS$, and $\angle R$ and $\angle Q$ are again consecutive interior angles. Thus, by the consecutive interior angle theorem, $\angle R$ and $\angle Q$ must be supplementary, and thus, $m\angle R + m\angle Q = 180^\circ$. Then, we substitute to get

$$m\angle R + 124 = 180^\circ$$

and therefore
$$m \angle R = 56^\circ$$